# Razor with icon in textBox HTML.Label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a question

If I do this:

```
<label>First name<i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></label>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "", @id = "FirstName1" })

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

I get a text saying First name and a textbox with a little icon

Is it possible to create the same thing with

```
@Html.Label("FirstName", "First name")
```

or

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

The icon that is created is in the textbox and I really cant figure out how to get it in there with razor

Comment: Short answer is no. You need to create the `<label>` manually, but you can use `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` for the display text (and `for="@Html.IdFor()"` if you do not wrap the label round the control) to strong type it to the model. Alternatively you can create you own extension method to generate the correct html.

Comment: can you add screen shot how it is looking like

Comment: Stephen. Is it possible to show an example. I tried DisplayNameFor but then it sets the text in center and not to the right above the textfield

Comment: `<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.FirstName)">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)<i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></label>` (and you need to remove your `@id = "FirstName1"` - but why would you want to override the default `id="FirstName"` anyway?)

Comment: I havent written this code but I think it is override becasue they want to check if the code have been changed or not before leaving the page

Comment: @MikaelFloberg, Your last comment makes no sense

Comment: @StephenMucecke Well they have done it like this.  In a jquery  var flag = false;
            var firstname = data1.FirstName == null ? "" : data1.FirstName;
            if ($("#FirstName1").val() != firstname)
            {
                flag = true;

Comment: I guess you did not understand my comment - the `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)` generates `<input id="FirstName" .... />` - I was asking why you would want it to be `<input id="FirstName1" .... />`? (and `@class = ""` makes no sense at all)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well I am just trying to figure out how it shall be written the correct way using mvc razor. I havent done this code and want to see if I can learn something. How would you write the code above if you are able to deside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166743/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mikael-floberg).